# control volume using python script

Tags: 14.04, python, pulseaudio, alsa, amixer

I can control volume using this command through terminal `amixer -D pulse sset Master 0%` .
My question that how can I do the same thing using python script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `call` from the `subprocess` module:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "0%"])
```

[Source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#long)

Of course, you can use the normal python code with it:

```
valid = False

while not valid:
    volume = input('What volume? > ')

    try:
        volume = int(volume)

        if (volume <= 100) and (volume >= 0):
            call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", str(volume)+"%"])
            valid = True

    except ValueError:
        pass
```

This code will loop untill the user gives a valid input - between 0 and 100, and will then set the volume to that.

This will run in Python 3. Change the `input` to `raw_input` for Python 2.

---

To increase by 10% when the script is run you can do one of two things.

You can use the `alsaaudio` module.

First, install with

```
sudo apt-get install python-alsaaudio
```

and then import it:

```
import alsaaudio
```

we can get the volume:

```
>>> m = alsaaudio.Mixer()
>>> vol = m.getvolume()
>>> vol
[50L]
```

we can also set the volume:

```
>>> m.setvolume(20)
>>> vol = m.getvolume()
>>> vol
[20L]
```

This number is a [long integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python) in a list. So to make it into a usable number, we can do `int(vol[0])`.

So to increase by 10% when it is run?

```
import alsaaudio
m = alsaaudio.Mixer()
vol = m.getvolume()
vol = int(vol[0])

newVol = vol + 10
m.setvolume(newVol)
```

---

Or we can stick with the `subprocess` module and default Ubuntu commands:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "10%+"])
```

will increase by 10%.

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: thanx, it worked . Can we do this by importing alsaaudio in python and execute this based on initial volume.

Comment: @tarun14110 i.e. get the current volume and add an amount? Sure

Comment: instead of asking from the user , can't I read the value of volume from my system itself ? Like whenever someone runs the script, the volume increases by 10%.

Comment: okk, got it thanks for helping , we can increase volume by 10% from the current volume by using this coomand  "amixer -D pulse sset Master 10%+"

Comment: @tarun14110 yes, or you can use the `alsaaudio` module, but that needs installing.

Comment: I have installed alsaaudio module , I have tried the thing you told about , but I am getting error "Unable to find mixer control 'Master',0
" How can I resolve that ?

Comment: @tarun14110 I'm not sure, sorry. I guess an issue with hardware. You can always use the 5%+

Comment: @tarun14110 for some reason I can't get to `pyalsaaudio`. I also don't know what is `amixer`. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

For me, Tim's code didn't quite work. I had to do this:

```
import alsaaudio
m = alsaaudio.Mixer(alsaaudio.mixers[0]) # alsaaudio.mixers = ["PCM"] for me.
m.setvolume(90) # Or whatever
```

It may be due to my weird / broken `.asoundrc` config file. But given that there is no actual reference documentation for `.asoundrc` - just some random examples - I don't think you can blame me.

Also please don't call out to command line programs to do it. That is ugly and error-prone.